# WPF application starting process with WaitForExit on UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a strange situation when my WPF application executes WINWORD process and wait for it to finish (method WaitForExit()).

Once user closes Word, there are two possibilities:

1. user closes Word after few seconds and everything goes well.
2. user closes Word after minute or more and application does not refresh UI anymore (this happens almost always). Immediately after Process.WaitForExit() application adds row to datagrid but it is not shown on UI. If user minimizes and restores window, it goes black. But it still reacts to mouse clicks if user hits button but it does not refresh Window UI anymore. This is reproducible on multiple computers.

In WinForms this was working for sure. I would really like to know the reason for such behavior in WPF. Could this be a problem to long block of WPF UI thread on Process.WaitForExit()?

btw, I didn't manage to start application in background thread and wait for it to finish in UI thread (I tried to show an information window that would be automatically closed when WINWORD closes).

Environment: Windows XP and Windows 7, .NET 4.0

Comment: Posting some code may get you more answers.

Comment: Aside from your problem, you should never ever block the UI thread. Just do that in a background task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variant for .NET 4.0:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = StartAndWaitProcess(@"some\document\path");
    t.ContinueWith(dummy => b.Content = "process finished",
                   TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

Task StartAndWaitProcess(string path)
{
    var p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    p.Exited += (sender, args) => { tcs.SetResult(true); p.Dispose(); };
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.Start());
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

For .NET 4.5 there is a nicer alternative

```
async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await StartAndWaitProcess(@"some\document\path");
    b.Content = "process finished";
}
```

(`StartAndWaitProcess` is the same.)

---

Old code, kept for consistency:

```
async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = Task.Run(() => StartAndWaitProcess(@"some\document\path"));
    await t;
    label.Content = "process finished";
}

void StartAndWaitProcess(string path)
{
    using(var p = Process.Start(path))
        p.WaitForExit();
}
```

This variant is worse, as it unnecessarily blocks a background thread for waiting.

Comment: Thank You, for such a quick response. I will check if it solves particular problem and will accept your answer tomorrow.For now, test application seems to do the work. Btw, Task.Run exists in .NET 4.5 and for those who use .NET 4.0., you should replace Task.Run with Task.Factory.StartNew.

Comment: @Voki: Well, for .NET 4.0 there is no `await`, so one needs to play with continuations manually.

Comment: They specifically said .NET 4.0 in their question, but the async stuff actually can be used in .NET 4.0 if you include Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack.Net4 into your project references. I don't remember if there are any more steps to get it to work, but I can't recall any at the moment.

Comment: @Jeremy, I used NuGet to install Async in my .NET 4.0 project and it added reference Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Deskop, I guess only these.

Comment: @Jeremy: indeed, I didn't take .NET 4 into account. Added a variant for .NET 4.

Comment: @Voki: Added a variant for .NET 4, so you can avoid the dependency on AsyncTargetingPack

Comment: @Voki: the new variant is superior to the old one, really.

Comment: @Vlad: Thank You very much. For .NET 4.0, VS suggests that I should put await in front of t.ContinueWith - and I do need it to wait there. Did You make an unintended mistake or ... ?

Comment: @Voki: For .NET 4, check that you are not using `async` on `Button_Click`. The variant for .NET 4 should work without `await`.

Comment: @Vlad: Thank You! It solved my problem and I also learned something new.

Comment: @Voki: You're welcome! (And: `async` is cool! Switch to .NET 4.5 as fast as you can.)

Comment: This is so close to being correct. But: there's no need to use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` just to call the `p.Start()` method. (And in .NET 4.5 and higher, should be `Task.Run()` anyway...but it's not needed then either, so...) There's no reason to keep the "old code, for consistency". No one cares about "consistency", when the "consistent" code shouldn't be used.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: On my system, `Process.Start` was sometimes (not always) pretty slow, causing noticeable UI glitches. So no, starting a task is necessary.